# Why replace() with regex change condition not result

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code:

```
var code = $('#code');
var str = code.val();
console.log(str);
var re = new RegExp("^press\\\(\\\"" + "KEY_6" + "\\\"\\\)\\n+(.*)", "m");
console.log(re);
var res = str.replace(re,'');
console.log(res);      
code.val(res);
```

When a user inputs this into textarea:

```
press("KEY_3")
press("KEY_6")
press("KEY_9")
```

It should replace **press("KEY_9")** with empty string. However, it also replaces the condition **press("KEY_6")**

Could you help me to understand possible reasons why it's not working as supposed? There's following link with example: http://jsfiddle.net/vfn8dtn4/

Comment: What are you trying to do? The regex is removing everything from the line containing `press(KEY_6)` and the next line.

Comment: You could simplify your regex into 'var re = new RegExp(".*KEY_9\".*[\r\n]+", "m");' to avoid matching more than you want. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfn8dtn4/3/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should capture the group you want to keep, and then replace with `$1`:

```
...
var re = new RegExp("^([\\s\\S]*press\\\(\\\"" + "KEY_6" + "\\\"\\\))[\\n\\r]+.*", "m");
console.log(re);
var res = str.replace(re,'$1');
...
```

See [updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/vfn8dtn4/5/)

Output:

```
press("KEY_6")
press("KEY_1")
press("KEY_6")
```

When we add `[\\s\\S]*` at the pattern start, we make sure we match as many characters as possible before the first `press`, so we'll capture the *last* `KEY_6`.

Comment: I thought it would work if there would be more than one KEY_6 it would remove last one and that's why i added it. But it seems if I got more than one KEY_6 it would change next line after first KEY_6 not last one.

Comment: Yes, the next line, as you have `\n` (go to next line) and `.*` that means *match all characters but a newline, as many as possible*. So, what is your expected output?

Comment: For Example, If I've:
press("KEY_6")
press("KEY_1")
press("KEY_6")
press("KEY_9")

I'd like to remove press("KEY_9") not press("KEY_1")

Answer (score 0):

The (.*) at the end is consuming all the characters coming after "KEY_6" and the new line character. If you remove that i.e.

```
"^press\\\(\\\"" + "KEY_6" + "\\\"\\\)\n+"
```

works fine

Comment: Please edit the answer or remove it. It is not helpful, as the line containing `KEY_6` should not be deleted. Also, `(.*)` is fine since OP needs to remove it. Usually, such answers are downvoted, don't make me do that :)